# Combining RAC Signals and receive all values

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

I'm trying to get familiar with Reactive Cocoa, and running into a issue when combining signals.

I understand combineLatest or zip will only send a value when all of the combined signals sent at least one value. But is it possible to combine signals and get a value if any of the signals send a value?

I have several signals that I would like to execute the same code when a value is sent, regardless if the other signals every sent a value or not. Am I approaching this the wrong way? or is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
RACSignal* a = ...
RACSignal* b = ...

RACSignal* combined = [[RACSignal 
    combineLatest:@[[a startWith:nil], [b startWith:nil]] 
    skip:1];
```

Here `startWith:` makes sure that all signals fire once at the beginning, producing a combined `[nil, nil]` tuple (which will be skipped by `skip:1`). Then, if for example `a` sends `@"foo"`, `combined` will send a tuple of `[@"foo", nil]`.